# Minimum pluses required to make the equation (x = y) correct

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14, dynamic-programming

> **Problem Statement**:
>
> Given an equation “x=y”, for example, “111=12”, you need to add pluses
> inside x to make the equation correct. In our example “111=12”, we can
> add one plus “11+1=12” and the equation becomes correct. You need to
> find the minimum number of pluses to add to x to make the equation
> correct. If there is no answer print -1.
>
> Note that the value of y won’t exceed 5000. The numbers in the
> corrected equation may contain arbitrary amounts of leading zeros.
>
> Input Format The first line contains a string, A as described in the
> problem statement.
>
> Constraints 1 <= len(A) <= 10^3

I tried the recursive approach. Which is for every character in the 'x', I have two options I can include the plus sign next to the current digit or move to the next digit (by including the current digit with the next digit) I checked all the combinations and found the minimum pluses. As you know, this is exponential in complexity. I'm not able to apply dynamic programming for this problem as I can't think of the states for the dynamic programming.

I know this problem can be solved by dynamic programming. But, I don't know **how to identify the state and the transition**.

Comment: This is not the right site to ask for help on solving general problems. It's a site for asking specific questions about programming.

Comment: @super: Huh? This is a specific algorithmic problem, which is entirely on-topic for SO according to the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (it lists "Software algorithms"). The only problem with this question is that the OP didn't show their attempts at solving it.

Comment: @YakovGalka If you want to call copy-pasting some programming quiz/problem a *specific algorithmic problem* you are more generous then me. Also, I think that fact that it fails to show any attempt at a solution or what parts of the problem OP is having an issue with makes it anything but specific. I could have worded that more carefully or precise, but I guess seeing this kind of post dumps 15 times a day makes you less eager to do so.

Comment: It does not show any effort, that part is true and also it should be more specific. However, this does qualify a programming problem though. @Naveen Kumar *Please mention your efforts in the question and be more specific on the part where you are facing problem*.

Comment: @AKSingh, Thanks for your response. I tried the recursive approach. Which is for every character in the 'x', I have two options I can include the plus sign next to the current digit  or move to the next digit (by including the current digit with the next digit)  I checked all the combinations and found the mininum pluses. As you know, this is exponential in complexity. I'm not able to apply  dynamic programming for this problem as I can't think of the states for the dp.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that comes to mind is to have a table

```
int f[N+1][M+1];
```

where `N = len(x)` and `M = y`. Then `f[i][j]` would record the solution to the sub-problem `substr(x,0,i)=j`; i.e. how many pluses are needed to get the sum `j` from the first `i` digits of `x`. The table can be incrementally updated through the recurrence relation:

```
f[i][j] = minimum over 0 <= k < i of (f[k][j - atoi(substr(x,k,i))] + 1)
```

Configurations that aren't obtainable or out-of-bounds should be understood as having `f[i][j] == +infinity` rather than `-1`.

The size of the table will be O(N*M) and the running time is O(N² M).

I'll leave the implementation details and the starting condition for you to complete.

Comment: The good approach according to me (+1). The running time O(N^2 M) seems too important. I understand it is an upper bound, in practice it should be much faster.

Comment: @Damien: depending on how you code the update you may skip values that are non-obtainable; then if `f` is sparse (which it is) you'll get O(NM) runtime. Might be a necessary optimization to get full score on a competition, but be unnecessarily complex for a university homework. Even the naive O(N^2 M) loop will have only 2.5 billiion iteration with the given constraints, which will complete in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Backtracking along with DP (Memoization) helped me to pass all the cases
here is my code. It passed all the cases in the given time limit

```
all_ans = {}
def min_pulses(A, target):
    
    if (A, target) in all_ans:
        return all_ans[(A, target)]
    
    if len(A) == 0:
        if target != 0:
            return -1
        else:
            return 0
        
    while len(A) > 0 and A[0] == '0':
        A = A[1:]
        
    if len(A) == 0 and target == 0:
        return 1
        
    if target < 0:
        return -1
    
    
    i = 1
    ans = float('inf')# initializing ans to infinite number so that min can be update
    
    while i <= 5 and i <=len(A):
        curr_num = A[:i]
        curr_ans = min_pulses(A[i:], target - int(curr_num))
        if curr_ans >= 0:
            ans = min(1 + curr_ans, ans)       
        
        i += 1
        
    if ans == float('inf'):
        ans = -1
        
        
    all_ans[(A,target)] = ans
    return ans

equation = input().split('=')
A = equation[0]
target = int(equation[1])

groups = min_pulses(A, target)

if groups < 0:
    print(-1)
    
else:
    print(groups - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
//import java.lang.Math;

class NewClass15{
    
    public static int minimum_pluses(String S)
    {
        
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        int target=0;
        for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++) //distinguishing left and right strings respectively
        {
            if(S.charAt(i)=='=')
            {
                target=Integer.parseInt(S.substring(i+1,S.length()));
                break;
            }
            s.append(S.charAt(i));
        }
        
        dp = new int[1000][5001][6];
        int temp = dfs(s.toString(),0,0,target);
        if(temp>=max)
            return -1;
        else
            return temp;
    }
    static int dp[][][];
    
    private static int dfs(String s,int len,int ind,int target)
    {
        if(target<0||len>5) return max;
        
        if(ind==s.length())
        {
            int x=0;
            if(len!=0)
                x=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(ind-len,ind));
            target-=x;
            
            if(target==0) return 0;
            
            return max;
              
        }
        
        if(dp[ind][target][len]!=0) 
        {
            System.out.println("1 dfs("+ind+","+target+","+len+")");
            return dp[ind][target][len]-1;
        }
        
        
        //add
        long ans=max;
        if(s.charAt(ind)=='0' && len==0)
        {
                        
            System.out.println("2 dfs("+0+","+(ind+1)+","+target+")");
            ans=Math.min(ans,dfs(s,0,ind+1,target));
            return (int)(ans);
        }
        
        System.out.println("3 dfs("+(len+1)+","+(ind+1)+","+target+")");
        ans=Math.min(ans,dfs(s,len+1,ind+1,target));
        
        //add +
        if(len!=0)
        {
            int x=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(ind-len,ind));
            int j=ind;
            while(j<s.length() && s.charAt(j)=='0') j++;
            
            if(j!=s.length()) j=j+1;
            
            System.out.println("4 dfs("+(1)+","+(j)+","+(target-x)+")");
            ans=Math.min(ans,1+dfs(s,1,j,target-x));
        }
        
        System.out.println("final dfs("+ind+","+target+","+len+")");
        dp[ind][target][len]=(int)(ans+1);
        return (int)(ans);
    }
    
    static int max=10000;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String A;
        A=scan.next();
        int result;
        result = minimum_pluses(A);
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

This is the answer in java if it is of some help. I have not written the code though.

Can you provide me with some testcases for the given Minimum Pluses Question?
Thank you.

Comment: What seems to be going wrong with the code you have written? (What is the bad output?)

Answer (score 0):

```
"""2nd one Answer"""
def permute(s):
    result = [[s]]
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        first = [s[:i]]
        rest = s[i:]
        for p in permute(rest):
            result.append(first + p)
    return [[int(j) for j in i] for i in result]
def problem(s):
    x,y=s.split("=")
    data=permute(x)
    newdata=[]
    for i in range(1,len(x)+1,1):
        for j in data:
            if i==len(j):
                newdata.append(j)
    for i in newdata:
        if sum(i)==int(y):
            print("str 1",i)
            return
    print("str -1")    
def check_constraint(s):
    if (not (1<=len(s)<=10^3)):
        print(-1)
    elif (s.split("=")[0]==s.split("=")[1]):
        print(1)
    elif (not (len(s.split("=")[0])>=len(s.split("=")[1]))):
        print(-1)
    else:
        problem(s)
A=input()
check_constraint(A)
```